# Retaining a field value when the value includes to other values from a separate field

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Imagine that we are a health plan and we have a database that records all of the claim line details for every claim a provider bills to us. I want to identify claim ids that were billed with two specific procedure codes. Here is a dummy dataset:

```
val df = Seq(
        ("153T32", "D0201"), 
        ("153T32", "D3303"), 
        ("153T32", "F2303"),
        ("421F32", "D0200"),
        ("421F32", "D1111"),
        ("421F32", "D0201"),
        ("991E32", "D0201"),
        ("991E32", "F2303"),
        ("991E32", "A1123"),
        ("529E52", "G1029"),
        ("529E52", "B0392")).
    toDF("claim_id", "code")
```

In this fake example, I want to identify the `claim_id` values that are associated with both `code === "D0201"` and `code === "F2303"`. I figured out how to do this creating two new DataFrames where each is filtered on one of the `code` values and then inner joining them together. But if there is a way to do this without creating to intermediary DataFrames, then I would like to see how you all would do it.

Here is my current solution:

```
val df1 = df.where($"code" === "D0201")
val df2 = df.where($"code" === "F2303")
val joinExpr = df1.col("claim_id") === df2.col("claim_id")

val finalDF = df1.join(df2, joinExpr, "inner").select(df1.col("claim_id"))

finalDF.show()
+--------+
|claim_id|
+--------+
|  153T32|
|  991E32|
+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there are no duplicated rows in the original data frame, here is one approach without joining:

```
(df.where($"code".isin("D0201", "F2303"))
   .groupBy("claim_id").agg(count($"code").as("cnt"))
   .where($"cnt" === 2).select("claim_id")
).show
+--------+                                                                      
|claim_id|
+--------+
|  153T32|
|  991E32|
+--------+
```